# google Gcm can't switch to google Fcm

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I used rpush Gcm to send notification, Now I want to Change Google Gcm to new version of Google Fcm, Then I install rpush version 2.7.0,this version is to use Fcm to send notification,however the file "delivery.rb" still be the old link "https://gcm.googleapis.com",not new version link "https://fcm.googleapis.com",what's the matter with the issue?need your help,thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [thread](https://github.com/rpush/rpush/issues/284), updating endpoints is not strictly required, as Google will continue to support the existing GCM endpoints. Also based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm#update_server_endpoints), be noted of that the new FCM version of `gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/` is `fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/` **(without "http")**.